# Msys Mingw64 C++ Segmentation fault with Mysql Connector mysqlcppconn

Tags: c++, mysql, segmentation-fault, msys2

I'm running msys2 mingw64 bit (installed from msys2-x86_64-20161025.exe) and trying to compile and run some C++ code which will connect to a local mysql instance. I have managed to compile but get a segfault on run. Details below: What have I missed?

```
./test.exe
Segmentation fault
```

My code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include <driver.h>
#include <exception.h>
#include <resultset.h>
#include <statement.h>

using namespace sql;
int main(void){
  sql::Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;

  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306","root","coolpasswd");

  return 0;
}
```

Compile

```
g++ -Wall -I /c/Program\ Files/MySQL/Connector\ C++\ 1.1/include/  -I /c/Program\ Files/MySQL/Connector\ C++\ 1.1/include/cppconn -I /c/msys64/mingw32/include/ -L  /c/Program\ Files/MySQL/Connector\ C++\ 1.1/lib/opt -o test test.cpp -lmysqlcppconn --verbose
```

My Path

```
export PATH=/c/Program\ Files/MySQL/Connector\ C++\ 1.1/lib/opt:$PATH
```

strace test.exe

```
    [SNIP]
    create_child: test.exe
       45   12365 [main] test 21024 posify_maybe: env var converted to PATH=/c/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 1.1/lib/opt:/c/php-7.0.27-Win32-VC14-x64:/mingw64/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
      108   12473 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x600039170: PATH=/c/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 1.1/lib/opt:/c/php-7.0.27-Win32-VC14-x64:/mingw64/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
       78   12551 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x600028D30: PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
       75   12626 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x600028D80: PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig:/mingw64/share/pkgconfig
       75   12701 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x600028DD0: PRINTER=Adobe PDF
       72   12773 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x600028DF0: PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
       72   12845 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x600028E20: PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 45 Stepping 6, GenuineIntel
       74   12919 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x600028E70: PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
       71   12990 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x600028E90: PROCESSOR_REVISION=2d06
       72   13062 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x6000392B0: PROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files
       71   13133 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x6000392E0: PROMPT=$P$G
       76   13209 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x600039300: PS1=\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[35m\]$MSYSTEM\[\e[0m\] \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$
       73   13282 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x600039370: PSModulePath=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
       75   13357 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x6000393F0: PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
       72   13429 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x600039410: PWD=/c/Users/tomk/Documents/of_v0.9.8_msys2_release/examples/video/videoPlayerTomek
       71   13500 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x600039470: ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
       72   13572 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x6000394A0: ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
       73   13645 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x6000394E0: ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
       82   13727 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x600039510: SESSIONNAME=Console
       72   13799 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x600039530: SHELL=/usr/bin/bash
       70   13869 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x600039550: SHLVL=1
       70   13939 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x600039570: SYSTEMDRIVE=C:
       72   14011 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x600039590: SYSTEMROOT=C:\WINDOWS
       71   14082 [main] test 21024 getwinenv: can't set native for TEMP= since no environ yet
       39   14121 [main] test 21024 mount_info::conv_to_posix_path: conv_to_posix_path (C:\msys64\tmp, 0x10000000, no-add-slash)
       45   14166 [main] test 21024 normalize_win32_path: C:\msys64\tmp = normalize_win32_path (C:\msys64\tmp)
       40   14206 [main] test 21024 mount_info::conv_to_posix_path:  mount[0] .. checking / -> C:\msys64
       40   14246 [main] test 21024 mount_info::conv_to_posix_path: /tmp = conv_to_posix_path (C:\msys64\tmp)
      102   14348 [main] test 21024 win_env::add_cache: posix /tmp
       40   14388 [main] test 21024 win_env::add_cache: native TEMP=C:\msys64\tmp
       41   14429 [main] test 21024 posify_maybe: env var converted to TEMP=/tmp
      102   14531 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x600039610: TEMP=/tmp
       74   14605 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x6000395B0: TERM=xterm
       71   14676 [main] test 21024 getwinenv: can't set native for TMP= since no environ yet
       40   14716 [main] test 21024 mount_info::conv_to_posix_path: conv_to_posix_path (C:\msys64\tmp, 0x10000000, no-add-slash)
       42   14758 [main] test 21024 normalize_win32_path: C:\msys64\tmp = normalize_win32_path (C:\msys64\tmp)
       40   14798 [main] test 21024 mount_info::conv_to_posix_path:  mount[0] .. checking / -> C:\msys64
       41   14839 [main] test 21024 mount_info::conv_to_posix_path: /tmp = conv_to_posix_path (C:\msys64\tmp)
      101   14940 [main] test 21024 win_env::add_cache: posix /tmp
       39   14979 [main] test 21024 win_env::add_cache: native TMP=C:\msys64\tmp
       41   15020 [main] test 21024 posify_maybe: env var converted to TMP=/tmp
      102   15122 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x600039690: TMP=/tmp
       71   15193 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x600039630: TZ=Europe/London
       71   15264 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x6000396B0: USER=tomk
       70   15334 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x6000396D0: USERDOMAIN=DESKTOP-HBTHS30
       71   15405 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x600039700: USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=DESKTOP-HBTHS30
       74   15479 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x600039740: USERNAME=tomk
       70   15549 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x600039760: USERPROFILE=C:\Users\tomk
       71   15620 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x600039790: WD=C:\msys64\usr\bin\
       75   15695 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x6000397B0: WINDIR=C:\WINDOWS
       70   15765 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x6000397D0: _=/usr/bin/strace
       71   15836 [main] test 21024 getwinenv: can't set native for TEMP= since no environ yet
       39   15875 [main] test 21024 mount_info::conv_to_posix_path: conv_to_posix_path (C:\Users\tomk\AppData\Local\Temp, 0x10000000, no-add-slash)
       41   15916 [main] test 21024 normalize_win32_path: C:\Users\tomk\AppData\Local\Temp = normalize_win32_path (C:\Users\tomk\AppData\Local\Temp)
       40   15956 [main] test 21024 mount_info::conv_to_posix_path:  mount[0] .. checking / -> C:\msys64
       41   15997 [main] test 21024 mount_info::conv_to_posix_path:  mount[1] .. checking /bin -> C:\msys64\usr\bin
       41   16038 [main] test 21024 mount_info::conv_to_posix_path: /c/Users/tomk/AppData/Local/Temp = conv_to_posix_path (C:\Users\tomk\AppData\Local\Temp)
      105   16143 [main] test 21024 win_env::add_cache: posix /c/Users/tomk/AppData/Local/Temp
       39   16182 [main] test 21024 win_env::add_cache: native TEMP=C:\Users\tomk\AppData\Local\Temp
       40   16222 [main] test 21024 posify_maybe: env var converted to TEMP=/c/Users/tomk/AppData/Local/Temp
      104   16326 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x6000395D0: TEMP=/c/Users/tomk/AppData/Local/Temp
       73   16399 [main] test 21024 getwinenv: can't set native for TMP= since no environ yet
       38   16437 [main] test 21024 mount_info::conv_to_posix_path: conv_to_posix_path (C:\Users\tomk\AppData\Local\Temp, 0x10000000, no-add-slash)
       40   16477 [main] test 21024 normalize_win32_path: C:\Users\tomk\AppData\Local\Temp = normalize_win32_path (C:\Users\tomk\AppData\Local\Temp)
       41   16518 [main] test 21024 mount_info::conv_to_posix_path:  mount[0] .. checking / -> C:\msys64
       42   16560 [main] test 21024 mount_info::conv_to_posix_path:  mount[1] .. checking /bin -> C:\msys64\usr\bin
       41   16601 [main] test 21024 mount_info::conv_to_posix_path: /c/Users/tomk/AppData/Local/Temp = conv_to_posix_path (C:\Users\tomk\AppData\Local\Temp)
      108   16709 [main] test 21024 win_env::add_cache: posix /c/Users/tomk/AppData/Local/Temp
       40   16749 [main] test 21024 win_env::add_cache: native TMP=C:\Users\tomk\AppData\Local\Temp
       39   16788 [main] test 21024 posify_maybe: env var converted to TMP=/c/Users/tomk/AppData/Local/Temp
      104   16892 [main] test 21024 win32env_to_cygenv: 0x600039650: TMP=/c/Users/tomk/AppData/Local/Temp
       46   16938 [main] test 21024 pinfo_init: Set nice to 0
       40   16978 [main] test 21024 pinfo_init: pid 21024, pgid 21024, process_state 0x41
       40   17018 [main] test 21024 App version:  2009.0, api: 0.318
       41   17059 [main] test 21024 DLL version:  2010.0, api: 0.325
       40   17099 [main] test 21024 DLL build:    2018-02-09 15:25
       55   17154 [main] test 21024 dtable::extend: size 32, fds 0x180306130
      130   17284 [main] test 21024 __get_lcid_from_locale: LCID=0x0809
      410   17694 [main] test 21024 transport_layer_pipes::connect: Try to connect to named pipe: \\.\pipe\msys-dd50a72ab4668b33-lpc
       68   17762 [main] test 21024 transport_layer_pipes::connect: Error opening the pipe (2)
       74   17836 [main] test 21024 client_request::make_request: cygserver un-available
     1009   18845 [main] test 21024 reg_key::build_reg: failed to create key ServicesForNFS in the registry
    --- Process 21024 loaded C:\Windows\System32\netapi32.dll at 00007ff940e40000
    --- Process 21024 loaded C:\Windows\System32\samcli.dll at 00007ff93f600000
    --- Process 21024 loaded C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll at 00007ff9470f0000
    --- Process 21024 loaded C:\Windows\System32\samlib.dll at 00007ff93cc30000
    --- Process 21024 loaded C:\Windows\System32\netutils.dll at 00007ff946760000
     4345   23190 [main] test 21024 pwdgrp::fetch_account_from_windows: line: 
      810   24000 [main] test 21024 pwdgrp::fetch_account_from_windows: NetLocalGroupGetInfo(None) 1376
       54   24054 [main] test 21024 pwdgrp::fetch_account_from_windows: line: 
      751   24805 [main] test 21024 pwdgrp::fetch_account_from_windows: line: 
       50   24855 [main] test 21024 pwdgrp::fetch_account_from_windows: line: 
       42   24897 [main] test 21024 pwdgrp::fetch_account_from_windows: line: 
       43   24940 [main] test 21024 pwdgrp::fetch_account_from_windows: line: 
       44   24984 [main] test 21024 pwdgrp::fetch_account_from_windows: line: 
       42   25026 [main] test 21024 pwdgrp::fetch_account_from_windows: line: 
       43   25069 [main] test 21024 pwdgrp::fetch_account_from_windows: line: 
       43   25112 [main] test 21024 pwdgrp::fetch_account_from_windows: line: 
       42   25154 [main] test 21024 pwdgrp::fetch_account_from_windows: line: 
       46   25200 [main] test 21024 cygheap_user::ontherange: what 2, pw 0x180306480
       41   25241 [main] test 21024 cygheap_user::ontherange: HOME is already in the environment /home/tomk
       86   25327 [main] test 21024 build_argv: cmd = 'test.exe', winshell = 1, glob = 1
      140   25467 [main] test 21024 build_argv: argv[0] = 'test.exe'
       74   25541 [main] test 21024 build_argv: argc 1
      213   25754 [main] test 21024 build_fh_pc: created an archetype (0x1803077A0) for /dev/pty4(136/4)
       75   25829 [main] test 21024 build_fh_pc: fh 0x180307430, dev 00880004
       83   25912 [main] test 21024 fhandler_pipe::create: name \\.\pipe\msys-dd50a72ab4668b33-pty4-from-master, size 131072, mode PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE
       82   25994 [main] test 21024 fhandler_pipe::create: pipe busy
       48   26042 [main] test 21024 tty::exists: exists 1
      184   26226 [main] test 21024 set_posix_access: ACL-Size: 124
       93   26319 [main] test 21024 set_posix_access: Created SD-Size: 200
       40   26359 [main] test 21024 fhandler_pty_slave::open: (393): pty output_mutex (0x144): waiting -1 ms
       46   26405 [main] test 21024 fhandler_pty_slave::open: (393): pty output_mutex: acquired
       51   26456 [main] test 21024 tty::create_inuse: cygtty.slave_alive.4 0x154
       42   26498 [main] test 21024 fhandler_pty_slave::open: (396): pty output_mutex(0x144) released
       91   26589 [main] test 21024 open_shared: name cygpid.19840, n 19840, shared 0x150000 (wanted 0x0), h 0x158, *m 6
       52   26641 [main] test 21024 fhandler_pty_slave::open: dup handles directly since I'm the owner
       64   26705 [main] test 21024 fhandler_pty_slave::open: duplicated from_master 0x3C8->0x158 from pty_owner
       45   26750 [main] test 21024 fhandler_pty_slave::open: duplicated to_master 0x3D4->0x160 from pty_owner
       41   26791 [main] test 21024 fhandler_pty_slave::open: duplicated to_master_cyg 0x3DC->0x164 from pty_owner
       73   26864 [main] test 21024 fhandler_console::need_invisible: invisible_console 0
       48   26912 [main] test 21024 fhandler_base::open_with_arch: line 458:  /dev/pty4 usecount + 1 = 1
       43   26955 [main] test 21024 fhandler_base::set_flags: flags 0x10002, supplied_bin 0x0
       43   26998 [main] test 21024 fhandler_base::set_flags: O_TEXT/O_BINARY set in flags 0x10000
       59   27057 [main] test 21024 fhandler_base::set_flags: filemode set to binary
       60   27117 [main] test 21024 _pinfo::set_ctty: old no ctty, ctty device number 0xFFFFFFFF, tc.ntty device number 0x880004 flags & O_NOCTTY 0x0
       45   27162 [main] test 21024 _pinfo::set_ctty: cygheap->ctty 0x0, archetype 0x1803077A0
       41   27203 [main] test 21024 _pinfo::set_ctty: ctty was NULL
       41   27244 [main] test 21024 _pinfo::set_ctty: line 497:  /dev/pty4 usecount + 1 = 2
       43   27287 [main] test 21024 _pinfo::set_ctty: /dev/pty4 ctty, usecount 2
       59   27346 [main] test 21024 _pinfo::set_ctty: attaching ctty /dev/pty4 sid 21024, pid 21024, pgid 21024, tty->pgid 20196, tty->sid 19636
       55   27401 [main] test 21024 _pinfo::set_ctty: cygheap->ctty now 0x1803077A0, archetype 0x1803077A0
       45   27446 [main] test 21024 fhandler_pty_slave::open_setup: /dev/pty4 opened, usecount 2
       44   27490 [main] test 21024 fhandler_base::set_flags: flags 0x10002, supplied_bin 0x0
       40   27530 [main] test 21024 fhandler_base::set_flags: O_TEXT/O_BINARY set in flags 0x10000
       40   27570 [main] test 21024 fhandler_base::set_flags: filemode set to binary
       41   27611 [main] test 21024 _pinfo::set_ctty: old ctty /dev/pty4, ctty device number 0x880004, tc.ntty device number 0x880004 flags & O_NOCTTY 0x0
       43   27654 [main] test 21024 _pinfo::set_ctty: attaching ctty /dev/pty4 sid 19636, pid 21024, pgid 20196, tty->pgid 20196, tty->sid 19636
       43   27697 [main] test 21024 _pinfo::set_ctty: cygheap->ctty now 0x1803077A0, archetype 0x1803077A0
       41   27738 [main] test 21024 fhandler_pty_slave::open_setup: /dev/pty4 opened, usecount 2
       99   27837 [main] test 21024 build_fh_pc: found an archetype for (null)(136/4) io_handle 0x158
       42   27879 [main] test 21024 build_fh_pc: fh 0x180307B80, dev 00880004
       44   27923 [main] test 21024 fhandler_base::open_with_arch: line 478:  /dev/pty4 usecount + 1 = 3
       42   27965 [main] test 21024 fhandler_base::set_flags: flags 0x10002, supplied_bin 0x0
       39   28004 [main] test 21024 fhandler_base::set_flags: O_TEXT/O_BINARY set in flags 0x10000
       40   28044 [main] test 21024 fhandler_base::set_flags: filemode set to binary
       40   28084 [main] test 21024 _pinfo::set_ctty: old ctty /dev/pty4, ctty device number 0x880004, tc.ntty device number 0x880004 flags & O_NOCTTY 0x0
       43   28127 [main] test 21024 _pinfo::set_ctty: attaching ctty /dev/pty4 sid 19636, pid 21024, pgid 20196, tty->pgid 20196, tty->sid 19636
       43   28170 [main] test 21024 _pinfo::set_ctty: cygheap->ctty now 0x1803077A0, archetype 0x1803077A0
       41   28211 [main] test 21024 fhandler_pty_slave::open_setup: /dev/pty4 opened, usecount 3
       41   28252 [main] test 21024 fhandler_base::set_flags: flags 0x10002, supplied_bin 0x0
       41   28293 [main] test 21024 fhandler_base::set_flags: O_TEXT/O_BINARY set in flags 0x10000
       40   28333 [main] test 21024 fhandler_base::set_flags: filemode set to binary
       41   28374 [main] test 21024 _pinfo::set_ctty: old ctty /dev/pty4, ctty device number 0x880004, tc.ntty device number 0x880004 flags & O_NOCTTY 0x0
       42   28416 [main] test 21024 _pinfo::set_ctty: attaching ctty /dev/pty4 sid 19636, pid 21024, pgid 20196, tty->pgid 20196, tty->sid 19636
       40   28456 [main] test 21024 _pinfo::set_ctty: cygheap->ctty now 0x1803077A0, archetype 0x1803077A0
       41   28497 [main] test 21024 fhandler_pty_slave::open_setup: /dev/pty4 opened, usecount 3
       96   28593 [main] test 21024 build_fh_pc: found an archetype for (null)(136/4) io_handle 0x158
       42   28635 [main] test 21024 build_fh_pc: fh 0x180307EF0, dev 00880004
       44   28679 [main] test 21024 fhandler_base::open_with_arch: line 478:  /dev/pty4 usecount + 1 = 4
       42   28721 [main] test 21024 fhandler_base::set_flags: flags 0x10002, supplied_bin 0x0
       38   28759 [main] test 21024 fhandler_base::set_flags: O_TEXT/O_BINARY set in flags 0x10000
       40   28799 [main] test 21024 fhandler_base::set_flags: filemode set to binary
       40   28839 [main] test 21024 _pinfo::set_ctty: old ctty /dev/pty4, ctty device number 0x880004, tc.ntty device number 0x880004 flags & O_NOCTTY 0x0
       42   28881 [main] test 21024 _pinfo::set_ctty: attaching ctty /dev/pty4 sid 19636, pid 21024, pgid 20196, tty->pgid 20196, tty->sid 19636
       41   28922 [main] test 21024 _pinfo::set_ctty: cygheap->ctty now 0x1803077A0, archetype 0x1803077A0
       41   28963 [main] test 21024 fhandler_pty_slave::open_setup: /dev/pty4 opened, usecount 4
       42   29005 [main] test 21024 fhandler_base::set_flags: flags 0x10002, supplied_bin 0x0
       40   29045 [main] test 21024 fhandler_base::set_flags: O_TEXT/O_BINARY set in flags 0x10000
       40   29085 [main] test 21024 fhandler_base::set_flags: filemode set to binary
       40   29125 [main] test 21024 _pinfo::set_ctty: old ctty /dev/pty4, ctty device number 0x880004, tc.ntty device number 0x880004 flags & O_NOCTTY 0x0
       44   29169 [main] test 21024 _pinfo::set_ctty: attaching ctty /dev/pty4 sid 19636, pid 21024, pgid 20196, tty->pgid 20196, tty->sid 19636
       43   29212 [main] test 21024 _pinfo::set_ctty: cygheap->ctty now 0x1803077A0, archetype 0x1803077A0
       43   29255 [main] test 21024 fhandler_pty_slave::open_setup: /dev/pty4 opened, usecount 4
      498   29753 [main] test 21024 __set_errno: void dll_crt0_1(void*):992 setting errno 0
      552   30305 [main] test 21024 __get_lcid_from_locale: LCID=0x0809
      106   30411 [main] test 21024 __get_lcid_from_locale: LCID=0x0809
      141   30552 [main] test 21024 __get_lcid_from_locale: LCID=0x0809
      157   30709 [main] test 21024 __get_lcid_from_locale: LCID=0x0809
      145   30854 [main] test 21024 __get_lcid_from_locale: LCID=0x0809
      157   31011 [main] test 21024 __get_lcid_from_locale: LCID=0x0809
      953   31964 [main] test 21024 close: close(1)
       42   32006 [main] test 21024 fhandler_base::close_with_arch: line 1129:  /dev/pty4 usecount + -1 = 3
       41   32047 [main] test 21024 fhandler_base::close_with_arch: not closing archetype
       41   32088 [main] test 21024 close: 0 = close(1)
      466   32554 [main] test 21024 close: close(2)
       43   32597 [main] test 21024 fhandler_base::close_with_arch: line 1129:  /dev/pty4 usecount + -1 = 2
       41   32638 [main] test 21024 fhandler_base::close_with_arch: not closing archetype
       40   32678 [main] test 21024 close: 0 = close(2)
      324   33002 [main] test 21024 do_exit: do_exit (256), exit_state 1
       40   33042 [main] test 21024 void: 0x0 = signal (20, 0x1)
       41   33083 [main] test 21024 void: 0x0 = signal (1, 0x1)
       41   33124 [main] test 21024 void: 0x0 = signal (2, 0x1)
       40   33164 [main] test 21024 void: 0x0 = signal (3, 0x1)
       42   33206 [main] test 21024 fhandler_base::close_with_arch: line 1129:  /dev/pty4 usecount + -1 = 1
       41   33247 [main] test 21024 fhandler_base::close_with_arch: not closing archetype
       40   33287 [main] test 21024 init_cygheap::close_ctty: closing cygheap->ctty 0x1803077A0
       40   33327 [main] test 21024 fhandler_base::close_with_arch: closing passed in archetype 0x0, usecount 0
       42   33369 [main] test 21024 fhandler_pty_slave::cleanup: /dev/pty4 closed, usecount 0
       40   33409 [main] test 21024 fhandler_pty_slave::close: closing last open /dev/pty4 handle
       56   33465 [main] test 21024 fhandler_console::free_console: freed console, res 1
       43   33508 [main] test 21024 fhandler_pty_common::close: pty4  closing
       43   33551 [main] test 21024 dtable::delete_archetype: deleting element 0 for /dev/pty4(136/4)
       46   33597 [main] test 21024 getpid: 21024 = getpid()
       42   33639 [main] test 21024 proc_terminate: nprocs 0
       40   33679 [main] test 21024 proc_terminate: leaving
       51   33730 [main] test 21024 pinfo::exit: Calling ExitProcess n 0x100, exitcode 0x1
    --- Process 21024 thread 15896 exited with status 0x1
    --- Process 21024 thread 5380 exited with status 0x1
    --- Process 21024 thread 21328 exited with status 0x1
    --- Process 21024 thread 21296 exited with status 0x1
    --- Process 21024 exited with status 0x1
```

Comment: does `get_driver_instance()` return NULL? That would cause a segfault when you deref it when you do `driver->...`

Comment: Hey Morten, thanks for your response! I commented out <pre> con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306","root","coolpasswd");</pre> and it works.. so indeed get_driver_instance is returning something weird. Any suggestions to debug ?

Comment: No idea - I just noticed a segfault in combination with a function returning a pointer that got dereferenced without checking for != null. I couldn't (30 seconds on google) find the documentation for the code you're using. Check which errors would cause `get_driver_instance()` to return NULL.